# Change range of calculation depending on day of week

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Trying to Calculate numbers of hours worked per week.  Schedules that we have to create month by month.  Currently we are modifying 32 separate schedules every month (one for each employee center) to adjust payweek calculations for our employees.

[Link to Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t1c0CsH7WphRUSC-z6LqQnYAPzdiN1s6waxObshzlHc/edit?usp=sharing)

[Link to Specific Sheet to reference "AGENTS"](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t1c0CsH7WphRUSC-z6LqQnYAPzdiN1s6waxObshzlHc/edit#gid=478376598)

Currently monthly we need to adjust Column E throughJ to reflect the dates of week to calculate Saturday - Friday.  I would love to be able to have the sheet figure out the weeks and auto adjust.

Current Formula in E3: `=SUM(K3:L3)`

Dream Formula in E3: `=SUM(Saturday week 1 : friday week 1)`

Dream Formula in F3: `=SUM(Saturday week 2 : friday week 2)`

Not so concerned with the number of the Payweek, that is just something to keep me sane.

Comment: Can you simplify your question a bit? You've given a ton of information but it sounds like you are trying to do something farely simple that could be accomplished with OFFSET() or VLOOKUP/HLOOKUP - or maybe SUMIF().

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for your AGENTS sheet. Not sure why you gave us the other sheet.

```
=SUMIF($K$1:$N$1,"="&E$1,$K3:$N3)
```

It is autofillable:

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this formula (for cell E3) in your  sheet

```
=sumif($K$1:$AO$1,E2,$K$3:$AO$3)
```

**Edit**

Here is the implementation of the dream formula

```
=sumif(arrayformula(rounddown($K$2:$AO$2/7)),(rounddown($K$2/7)-1) + <weekNumber>, $K3:$AO3)
```

For example in cell E3, the value would be

```
=sumif(arrayformula(rounddown($K$2:$AO$2/7)),(rounddown($K$2/7)-1) + 1, $K3:$AO3)
```

Please check this [link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jr2Y2Ex15JnTrNrvH7MX4F7lDry8nPX4D_T-isutA9A/edit#gid=32590000)

**Edit (for Excel)**

Array Formulas in excel work in a different way. There is no function "ArrayFormula", but array formulas can be created by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`. This encapsulates your formula in curly braces `{ }`. Remember this is automatically generated by Excel and are not entered via keyboard's `{` or `}` key. These are added automatically when user presses `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

In excel you will need to change the formula to

```
=SUM(IF(ROUNDDOWN($K$2:$AO$2/7,0)=ROUNDDOWN($K$2/7,0)-1+ <weekNumber>, $K$3:$AO$3, 0))
```

and press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

So for cell E3, enter this formula

```
=SUM(IF(ROUNDDOWN($K$2:$AO$2/7,0)=ROUNDDOWN($K$2/7,0) - 1+ 1, $K$3:$AO$3, 0))
```

and press `Ctrl + Shift + Enter`

Comment: This works great in the Google Spreadsheet, however when i try to download as an XLS is it not liking those formulas at all.  It strips everything away.  Is there a "neutral" ground that google and MS have for these types of formulas?


=sumif(arrayformula(rounddown($K$2:$AO$2/7)),(rounddown($K$2/7)-1) + 1, $K3:$AO3)

i can not find an equivalent of the arrayformula( in excel to fix the formula.   Thanks for your help! much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind utilizing your week numbers for the calculations you can use the SUMIF formula like this:

```
=SUMIF($K$1:$AO$1, E$2, $K3:$AO3)
```

The '$' prevents the cell reference from changing as you copy and paste it to different cells.

This formula will add up all of the cells in the 3rd row (`$k3:$AO3` where the value in the 1st row `$K$1:$AO$1` matches the value in `E2`). When you copy the formula to the right it will automatically change like this:

```
=SUMIF($K$1:$AO$1, F$2, $K3:$AO3)
```

And when you copy the formula down it will automatically change like this:

```
=SUMIF($K$1:$AO$1, E$2, $K4:$AO4)
```

Additionally, to automatically assign the week numbers you can replace your first row with this formula:

```
=WEEKNUM(K2)+IF(WEEKDAY(K2) = 7, 1, 0)
```

This formula calculates the week number, but since Google doesn't have a Saturday-Friday option we have to bump the week number up by one for Saturday `IF(WEEKDAY(K2) = 7, 1, 0)`.